# Existing Warmth/Competence Dictionaries for NLP?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, nlp

I am doing text analysis for feedback left for a large set of employees. I am a researcher and want to assign a "warmth" score to each comment (warmth = comments like "Jerry is friendly!" "Sarah is kind!"), and also a competence score (e.g. "Anna is very capable." "Jack is very skilled at programming."). Before I build out my own dictionaries to embody these concepts, I wanted to see if there are any existing dictionaries out there. I know there are many dictionaries for negative/positive words, but that's not what I am trying to do. I am using R to analyze the data, but any dictionary in an importable format would work. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this with a dictionary. You need to train a model.

Comment: I think I can do basic word counts with a dictionary. Training a model would allow me to do word embeddedness, but I am looking for something a bit simpler. R can take a dictionary of words and calculate how many warmth-related words are in a string and how many competence-related words are in that same string, but first it needs a dictionary (which I don't yet have). Sounds like I will need to create one.

Comment: All sentiment is sensitive to context. If you just count 'negative words' you'll get very inaccurate sentiment.

Comment: There are datasets for e.g. love, joy, anger, sadness, fear, surprise. E.g. see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03892.pdf  I'm not aware of any that specifically cover warmth and competence.

Comment: Great, thanks Darren!